# $\bigcup_{n}V_n$ is dense in $V$ (Hilbert spaces)

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces

I read:

> $\bigcup_{n}V_n$ is dense in $V$ (Hilbert spaces)

Does this mean: for every $v \in V$, there is a sequence $\{v_n\}$ with $v_n \in V_n$ for each $n$ such that $|v_n - v|_V \to 0$?

I guess so. But then I also read

> $V_n$ is dense in $V$

Does the author mean by this that given $v$, we can pick an $N$ such that there is an element $v_N \in V_N$ that is arbitrary close to $v$?

Are these two statements equivalent then?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> *Definition*. A subset $U \subseteq V$ is called **dense** in $V$ iff for each $v \in V$ there is a sequence $(u_k) \in {}^{\mathbb N}U$ with $u_k \to u$.

Lets apply this to your two cases: In the first case we are given that for any $v \in V$ there is a sequence $(u_k)$ with $u_k \in \bigcup_n V_n$ and $u_k \to v$. If moreover the $V_n$ are increasing, that is $V_1 \subseteq V_2 \subseteq \cdots$ we can arrange that $u_n \in V_n$ as you say. In general this is not possible (think of $V_{2n} = \{0\}$ for all $n$ or something like that).

The second one is easier: $V_n$ being dense means that for each $v \in V$ there is a sequence $(u_k)$ *of elements from $V_n$* converging to $v$, or in $V_n$ there are elements arbitrarily close to $v$.